# Sortable behavior for Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, jquery-ui-sortable

Does anyone know of an existing implementation of a sortable behavior for Doctrine? I'm actually amazed is isn't in the default behaviors since it's such a common thing in most webapplications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one in GitHub here:

http://github.com/jdudek/doctrine-sortable

(the doctrine-project.org link at this time is 404)

Answer (score 0):

after some creative googleing i've found out about this plugin: http://www.doctrine-project.org/extension/Sortable !!!

Comment: Oops! The page you asked for could not be found.

http://www.doctrine-project.org/extension/Sortable

Answer (score 0):

Here's one

https://github.com/bshaffer/csDoctrineActAsSortablePlugin#readme

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question is too old, but here is [Doctrine Sortable Extension](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sortable.md) on github.

And also [Knp Doctrine Behaviors Bundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/DoctrineBehaviors).